# SFDX - force:source:deploy ignoring apiVersion override?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx

Using the SFDX cli, I exported some metadata from a dev org using the manifest option along with a package.xml file. (The package .xml specified api version 37.0)

Now that i'm trying to push the same metadata into another Dev pro org, I'm trying to override the cli apiVersion using the following:

`sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=37.0 --global`

The command is successful, but my deployment still fails with the following:

```
    Property 'pageTemplate' not valid in version 45.0
    Property 'pageTemplate' not valid in version 45.0
    Property 'picklist' not valid in version 45.0 (115:13)
    Property 'picklist' not valid in version 45.0 (179:13)
    Property 'picklist' not valid in version 45.0 (263:13)
    Property 'picklist' not valid in version 45.0 (296:13)
    Property 'picklist' not valid in version 45.0 (352:13)
```

Can anyone guess why the config value is being ignored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play and could set and list the `apiVersion` (but not random names) so the set part seems to work. Then when I do an `sfdx force:source:push` this is echoed:

> WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "42.0"

If you are not seeing that then I presume the command you are running does not respect that setting.

(Reading the [CLI Runtime Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_config_values.htm), there is mention of the `sourceApiVersion` that is set in the `sfdx-project.json` file. But that only relates to scratch orgs presumably.)

Comment: Keith thank you, it was instead that I needed to set "sourceApiVersion". I guess "apiVersion" is related to the version of the CLI itself and not the metadata source

Comment: I got bitten by this today. Updating the `sourceApiVersion` in the `sfdx-project.json` file did the trick for me as well. Can confirm that this also affects using `force:source:deploy` to move things between orgs (non-scratch orgs) when not using a package.xml file (i.e. if you're using the `-p` or `-m` parameters)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a [Picklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm) & [PageTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) metadata defined.

Metadata `picklist` is only applicable with version 37.0 and earlier, this is now deprecated.

> Use this type in API version 37.0 and earlier only. In later versions, `picklist` is replaced by `valueset`.

And same with `pageTemplate`, which was available only until version 38.0:

> Use this field in API versions 33.0 to 38.0 only. In later versions, use `template`.

---

You will need to ensure that you update the `package.xml` to include these tags to be able to deploy it with version 38.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past this by changing the "sourceApiVersion" in the "sfdx-project.json" file to a higher version then restarting VS code. Looks like the value in the file is read when the extensions are initialising at startup. Worked afterwards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).